# Entity Framework Include Parent Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When I am accessing all cities my code is like this.

```
 public IQueryable<City> GetAll()
    {
        var result = from s in this.Context.Cities.Include("States.Countries") select s;
        return result;
    }
```

This is working fine and including states and countires. I want to get cities by Country Id, below is my code. In the below code, I want to include States.Countires for each city. How can i do this ?

```
public IEnumerable<City> GetByCountriesId(int Id)
    {
        var result = from s in this.Context.Countries
                     join a in this.Context.States on s.Id equals a.Country_Id
                     join b in this.Context.Cities on a.Id equals b.States_Id
                     where s.Id == Id 
                     select b;

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `this.Context.Cities.Include("State.Country").Where(c=>c.State.Country.Id==Id)` is enough if `City` and `State` has proper navigation properties.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?  I ask because that Include you're using, with a string argument, is older, and you should use the expression approach for compile time support.  For example:  '.Include(x => x.States)'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure a city could belong to several states? IMHO you should have a one to many relationship, where an `State` could have several `Cities` and a `City` should belong to one `State`. The same happens with `State` and `Country`. I think you have pluralized those nav. property names (`States` in `City` and `Cities` in `Country`) but there are not collections. In case you have those two one to many relationships in the same way that I describe above, you can write a query as I show as follow to achieve what you need:

```
 var result = this.Context.Cities.Include(c=>c.State.Country).Where(c=>c.State.Country.Id==Id‌​);
```

Is better use the [DbExtensions.Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx) extension method because is strongly typed.

Now, maybe you can think this query could end with a `NullReferenceException` due to the `c.State.Country.Id` expression in case one of those nav. properties could be `null`.But that is not going to happen because you need to set those navigation properties (or the FK properties in case that already exist in DB) when you need to save a new `City` or `State` in DB, in other word, they are *required*.

If you use Fluent Api to configure those relationships you will end with something like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasRequired(c=>c.State).WithMany(s=>s.Cities).HasForeignKey(c=>c.State_Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<State>().HasRequired(s=>s.Country).WithMany(c=>c.States).HasForeignKey(s=>s.Country_Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<City> GetByCountriesId(int id)
{
    return from country in this.Context.Countries
           where country.Id == id
           from state in country.States
           from c in this.Context.Cities.Include(c => c.States.Select(s => s.Countries))
           where c.States.Any(s => s == state)
           select c;
}
```

or, even better:

```
public IEnumerable<City> GetByCountryId(int id)
{
    return from c in this.Context.Cities
                     .Include(c => c.States.Select(s => s.Countries))
           where c.States.Any(s => s.Countries.Any(c => c.Id == id))
           select c;
}
```

However – while it's clear why `Country` has a `States` collection and `State` has a `Cities` collection – why does your `City` have a `States` collection and your `State` have a `Countries` collection? Shouldn't these be `State` and `Country` properties, respectively?

Assuming your `City` really does have a single `State`, and your `State` has a single `Country`, this simplifies it a lot:

```
return from c in this.Context.Cities
                 .Include(c => c.State.Select(s => s.Country))
       where c.State.Country.Id == id
       select c;
```